# OpenCV JavaCamera bug? (OpenCV 4 Android on Nexus 7)

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, logcat

I downloaded the samples from OpenCV for Android and let them run in eclipse on a real device (Nexus 7). They all work fine, but when I'm looking at the LogCat log, I see ca 20 errors displayed for each frame. The log is filled with them. Although all the samples work, this irritates me and makes it hard to debug the code.

Here a screenshot of the log:
[image: screenshot of logcat while running android OpenCV samples]

Does anyone know where these errors come from and what they mean?
Should I worry about them, if no: can I somehow hide them? if yes: what to do?

Another question:
I get, when running the JavaCameraView idle (Sample CameraPreview) only 15fps max. This is few, isn't it? Or is this always like this when using OpenCV with Java (over JNI) instead of c++?

Thanks in advance for any hints!
Isa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next OpenCV version will [fix a few camera bugs](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues?category_id=15&fixed_version_id=21&per_page=50&set_filter=1&status_id=%2a), maybe it fixes those messages. There is one specific to Nexus 7 2013, but looks different from yours.

JavaCamera is usually slower than NativeCamera but more stable (less buggy). But it also depends from other factors like ambient light (less light = slower), chosen resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really hope that this will be fixed. I don't have any other android device to test it on, so it may be only a problem on nexus 7. I used a resolution of 800x480 which is pretty low and nexus 7 is a fast device, so I still don't know why the framerate is so low.

Comment: You can always help the developers by reading carefully the Android camera bug list, check if yours is different from those, and if it is, submit a new bug report. That way maybe your bug is fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: I will certainly do that. So you think this is a bug?

Comment: If it happens with unchanged sample code I think it is likely.